# When should I use a single queue and when multiple ones?

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, stomp

I wonder, are there rules of when to create a single queue in RabbitMQ and when multiple ones? Or is it up to a producer whether or not send the messages to a single queue or multiple ones and technically there's no difference? Should it depend on the schema of the db, that is, should a single table correspond to a single queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> single queue in RabbitMQ and when multiple ones?

a single queue is a really bad idea. eventually you will want different types of messages to flow through rabbitmq. if you only have a single queue, you will end up reproducing the logic of how to decide which code should process the message, when RabbitMQ can do this for you with routing.

in general, each type of "work" to be done, represented by a message, should be it's own queue.

there will also be times when a specific message consumer will need it's own queue, even if the same types of messages are flowing to other queues.

> Or is it up to a producer whether or not send the messages to a single queue or multiple ones

the producer does not decide which queues the message it delivered to. the producer only knows which exchange to publish through. message consumers should be the ones deciding where the messages are delivered. the message consumer should be responsible for setting up the routing between the exchange and the destination queue.

there are exceptions to this, like every "good idea" in software development, but in general i find this to be true

> Should it depend on the schema of the db

your RabbitMQ configuration has zero correlation to your database. don't bother trying to map between the two. it will be painful, at best.

rather, look at behavior.

what type of behavior does this message need to trigger? what specific behavior is it, and which exchange / routing key should it be published with?

these are better questions that will lead you to a better RabbitMQ layout, with a focus on exchanges for groups of related messages, queues dedicated to a specific type of message consumer or a specific consumer, and routing keys that provide the logic to move a message from an exchange to the right queue.

...

i'd recommend reading some books on RabbitMQ, to get yourself rolling in the right direction with the basics of how RabbitMQ should be used, and then getting into good usage patterns and topology design:

- [RabbitMQ In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/rabbitmq-in-action) - from ground zero, what it is, why you should use it, how it works, etc. recommended for anyone looking at RMQ
- [RabbitMQ Layout](https://leanpub.com/rabbitmq-structures-and-layout) - understanding how RabbitMQ fits into various scenarios, as told through stories of developers solving problems - this is the "why-to" of RMQ topology design (exchanges, queues and bindings) <disclosure: the author of the answer is also the author of the recommended book>
- [RabbitMQ Patterns](https://leanpub.com/rmq-patterns) - understand message types, routing and common usage patterns in messaging systems, as applied to RabbitMQ - this is the core pattern "how-to" for application and topology design with RMQ <disclosure: the author of the answer is also the author of the recommended book>

Comment: Thanks. 
**the producer does not decide which queues the message it delivered to.** it does decide by specifying the name of a queue, doesn't it?

Comment: the producer specifies the exchange through which the message is published. the RabbitMQ bindings between the exchange and queue, using a routing key (if applicable) determine which queue the message is sent to. 2 exceptions: fanout queue, where routing key doesn't get used and default "direct" queue where routing key is the name of the destination queue. but, don't use the default direct queue. that's doing things backward, IME

Comment: and it also specifies the queue.

Comment: the parameters for publishing a message include the exchange name and routing key, but not the queue name. the default "direct" exchange uses the supplied routing key for the queue name, but this is not normal behavior. this is a special, built-in exchange type that i recommend not using. build your own exchanges, queues and bindings based on your system needs.

Comment: and what's the routing key if not the name of a queue?

Comment: that depends on the exchange type being used. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html has some basic examples. a routing key can look like "foo.bar.baz" and a "topic" exchange can have a binding of "ex.1" to "foo.*.baz" sending all those message to "someQueue" for example. the routing key is not the queue name - it's the address on the envelope, through which the postal system finds the actual mailbox

Comment: to continue the postal system analogy: you don't put the actual mailbox on the envelope. you put the address of the house on the enveloper and the postal service delivers the letter to the mailbox associated with that house. in RMQ, you put the routing key (address) on the message meta-data (envelope) and RMQ routes the message to the right queue (mailbox)